# for文のループが終わってから処理される

Tags: java, android

Android Studioでプログラミングを行っています。ランダムな数字が格納されているListからfor文で値を取り出しswitch文で処理をふりわけています。

button.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black)としている部分があるのですが
なぜかfor文の処理がすべて終わったあとに色が変わります。原因を教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
for(int r : randomList){
    try {
        sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    switch (r) {
        case 1:
            button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            break;
        case 2:
            button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            break;
        case 3:
            button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            break;
        case 4:
            button4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: 参考: [Java Android Thread sleepに関して(26015)｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/26015)

Answer (score 1):

ソースコードを読んでいないので推測を含みますが、`button.setBackgroundColor()`メソッドを呼び出しても、背景色を表す数値が`button`インスタンスに渡されるだけで、その値を参照して実際のボタンの背景色を変える処理が実行されていないからではないでしょうか。時間をおいて背景色をセットしたいということであれば、[このページ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080537/setbackgroundcolor-is-getting-ignored)が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ハンドラーだと確かに色は変わるのですが新たな問題が発生しました

Comment: @matomebutai 新たな問題であれば、こちらはクローズして別の質問をした方がいいかもしれませんね（状況によりますので、何とも言えませんが）。