# 条件がそろうまでコードを進ませたくない

Tags: android, java

javaのコードで入力待ちのためにwhileを使用すると画面がフリーズしてしまいます。C#では`Application.DoEvents()`というものがあり対処できたのですがJavaでフリーズさせない方法はあるのでしょうか？検索しても情報が見つからないので助けてほしいです。

```
int count = 0;

while(true){
    if(count == 4){
        break;
    }
}
```

countの値が4になるまで永遠に待ちたいのですが、whileを使用すると画面がフリーズします。どうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: イベントドリブンなプラットフォームで「待つ」のはダメ、と言うのは774RRさんの回答にある通りで、これはWindowsプログラミングでも同じで`Application.DoEvents()`についてはよくない裏技(残念ながら有名どころのサイトでも紹介されていますが)とされています。[Application.DoEvents メソッドを使うべきでない理由](https://blog.jhashimoto.net/entry/20111113/1321133064), [Application.DoEvents 禁止令!!](http://dotnetrevo.blog21.fc2.com/blog-entry-2.html)等々、英語記事を検索するともっといっぱい出てきます。ついでに言うと掲載されたような短い単純ループを回り続けている間はCPUコアの使用率が100%近くまで上がり、バッテリーをアホほど消費することになります。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 永遠に待ちたい

こういう待ち方をすると正常終了もできませんよ。待っちゃダメです。「待つ」という考え方を捨ててください。いまどき windows も android も「ハンドラの中で待つ」という処理は禁止されています。

提示質問文書だけでは具体的に何がしたいのかわかりませんが、
- ＊＊＊条件が成立したのち△△△をしたい
のなら
- ＊＊＊状況を変化させるハンドラの中で条件成立を判断する
- タイマーハンドラの中で条件成立を判断する
のように考えます。

[for文のループが終わってから処理される](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48854/)
[Listから取り出したボタンを　1秒まってからボタンの色を変えたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48866/)
どちらも「待つ」とダメという結論が出てますよね。

Comment: おっしゃりたいことはなんとなくわかりました。最近の実装でわかったことなのですが、timerやhandlerを使っても一定期間待機後に実行されるだけでメインのプログラムはすすみつづけていて、一瞬でプログラムが終わってしまうのです。待つ方法がないのはおかしいと思うのでもう少しさがしてみることにします

Comment: あとtimerハンドラーの中で条件成立はすでに実施済みですが、結局メインのプログラムは先に進んでしまうのでよい結果がえられませんでした

Comment: フツーに GUI なプログラムを作れば「勝手に進んでしまう」とか「一瞬で終わる」なんてことはなくて、終了イベントが到達するまで単に待機してくれるはずです。その間にマウスやキー操作やタイマー条件成立すれば、それ用のハンドラをシステムが呼んでくれる、ってことで。なんかその辺で齟齬がありそうですね。プロジェクトの作り方を見直してみてください。

Comment: ずーっと考えていましたが、おっしゃるとおりにハンドラの中で条件成立を判断するという思考にようやくシフトできました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1):

**解決(質問者自身による投稿)**

countを増やすボタンの中に条件判断とその先の処理を書く。

```
startbutton.setOnClickListener(new ViweOnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(){
//処理
}
});

//カウントを増やすボタン
button1.setOnClickListener(new ViewOnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(){
count++
if(count == 4){
//条件が成立したら先にすすむ
}
}
});
```

startbuttonイベントの中ですべての処理を完結させようとしていたことで「待つ」という考えになってしまっていました。